# getting an error when using lxml with BeauitfoulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to use lxml parser in my eclipse project using BeautifoulSoup:

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

I ran: `STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml --user` and got the result: `Successfully installed lxml-3.7.1`.

It appears that my computer isn't aware that the lxml parser is installed since I am getting an error:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Any idea what am I missing?

I am OSX, having both python3 and python2x versions installed.

Comment: What happens if you say `import lxml`?

Comment: it says: ImportError: No module named 'lxml'

Comment: Well then I guess you have not installed lxml.  So that's the question really.  This is more of a Pip issue I guess--you may want to edit to reflect this and re-tag.

Comment: after googling No module named 'lxml' , I found an answer saying that I should run STATIC_DEPS=true pip3 install lxml --user, instead of just pip. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

After running `pip3 install --upgrade pip` (`pip install --upgrade pip`) is not enough and `STATIC_DEPS=true pip3 install lxml --user` lxml parser is operational.